# how to set document title of new open window?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webapi

I am doing as below code to set document title for new open window

```js
var downloadWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank");
downloadWindow.document.title = "my title";
```

If we try to execute above snippet in console in google chrome, we can see while loading, We can see "my title", but same behaviour I want to be in internet explore?

How we can achieve same behaviour in internet explore?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var downloadWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank");
downloadWindow.document.write('<title>my title</title>');
```

Comment: Its showing and immediatly resetting with default one. Here my url is downloading something, so i want that title till the downloading gets completed. It works fine with GC

Comment: IE is showing the Access denied error may be due to security purposes. If you somehow managed to set it then also you will see the actual title of the window. Instead, try to inform the user in any other way. like, show the popup that shows some info and then open the new window. You can use this approach as a work around.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT. Doing analysis, I feels same.

Answer (score 0):

I think that due to security reasons, you will not able to see the modified title on the newly open window.

As a workaround, I suggest you try to display the alert message that informs the user that he is opening the downloading window.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
 <script>       
    alert("You are moving to download window...");  
    var downloadWindow = window.open("https://example.com", "_blank");
 </script>
</head>
<body>
   Test page
   
</body>
</html>
```

Let us know if you have any further questions. We will try to provide suggestions for it.